# how to send content from viewmodel to new page

Tags: c#, xaml

I have a pivot like this

```
<PivotItem Header="Product">
    <GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ProductViewModel.Products}">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Product">
                <StackPanel FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout="{StaticResource FlayoutBase1}" RightTapped="StackPanel_RightTapped">
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Price, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
</PivotItem>
```

I also have a flyout in every `Product` with a button and when I press it I want to send the values for `Name` and `Price` to a new page for the order of that product.
I don't know how to do it because they have different ViewModels and the fields are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

While navigating you can send parameters.

Check this for reference.

http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/how-to-pass-data-between-pages-in-windows-phone-alternatives

Comment: and how do it for windows 10 and between pivot items